# Get real client remote ip in docker-swarm httpd proxy?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I'm running a `httpd apache2` proxy in `docker swarm` mode with `docker stack deploy`.

Problem: when I access `mymachine:80`, the `access.log` only shows the remote ip of the docker `ingress` swarm network, like `10.0.0.2`. And not the real clients' ip.

Question: how can I tell swarm to retain the original IP address (maybe write it into another IP header?), without having to force my container or ports into `mode: host`?

Because I don't want to use zero-downtime deployment, which is what I have in docker-swarm mode without containers in host-mode.

Answer (score 1):

In short, there's no way to achieve this within the constraints you ask.

Docker swarm uses traffic forwarding, not listening ports, to handle ingress traffic. You can see telltale signs of this with `iptables -nL`, and noticing that the docker firewall rules (`DOCKER-USER`, `DOCKER-INGRESS`, etc) are in the `FORWARD` chain, not the `INPUT` chain (and every so often you'll see user caught by surprise, that their ingress firewall rules aren't blocking traffic).

As you pointed out, having your port on `mode: host` will solve the "real IP" issue (as the listening port will be on the host's "real" network namespace), but that prevents you from doing zero-downtime deployments (because the port is then a single resource in use).